# Remove characters "Before and After" certain character Jquery

Tags: jquery, regex

What I have is a string that contain special character , characters and integers and what I want out do is, do something like that, mentioned below:
Say I have string like `Radiobutton_12`. I want to remove all characters before "_". That worked as :

```
    var s = Radiobutton_12 
    s = s. Substring (s. indexOf ("_") +1);

    Same as I can remove character after all that. But what scenario demands is:

     radiobutton1_1, radiobutton2_1, radiobutton3_1

    What if I want to keep, 1 1, 2 1, 3 1
```

I am not getting that. Hoping any one could help me out.

Comment: can you tell what will be the expected o/p for RadiobuttonX_Y 

A) X 0r B) Y or C) X Y

Comment: like X Y

Radiobutton1_1set Radiobutton2_1set Radiobutton3_1set

Like: 
1 1 
2 1 
3 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it can be done in one-liner:

```
var arr = str.split(/\D+/).filter(Boolean);
```

**TESTING:**

```
arr = 'RadioButton11_12'.split(/\D+/).filter(Boolean);
["11", "12"]

arr = 'RadioButton_12'.split(/\D+/).filter(Boolean);
["12"]
```

Answer (score 1):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aW4b3/1/)**

```
var str='radiobutton1_1';
var str1=  'radiobutton2_1';
var str2=    'radiobutton3_1';

var spiltStr1=str.split('_');
var spiltStr2=str1.split('_');
var spiltStr3=str2.split('_');

alert(spiltStr1[0].replace( /^\D+/g, '')+" "+spiltStr1[1])
alert(spiltStr2[0].replace( /^\D+/g, '')+" "+spiltStr2[1])
alert(spiltStr3[0].replace( /^\D+/g, '')+" "+spiltStr3[1])
```

Comment: What if the value is RadioButton11_12?

Answer (score 0):

@Prabu Parthipan solution will solve your question but if you can use regex if you only want to take the numeric pairs out of the string.

```
var r = /\d+/g;
var s = "RadioButton11_12";
var m = s.match(r);

for(var i=0;i<m.length;i++){
    console.log(m[i]);
}
```